# Scheduling volunteers using VBA and need to eliminate duplicates for a given date.

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a program to randomly assign volunteers to different positions. There are 8 different spots on each date that need to be assigned to different volunteers. I have the code working except I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of duplicates. I added some code that prevents two spots in a row from being duplicates but that's as far as I got.

This is what the sheet looks like: (Notice that on the first date Connor Reilley is listed for two spots of the same position and Pierce Lewin is signed up for two different positions. That has to be changed).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    For j = 2 To jRows

    Assign:
        If wksCal.Range("C" & j) = "1st Reader" Or wksCal.Range("C" & j) = "2nd Reader" Then
    Lector:
            iRand = Int((iRows - 2) * Rnd())
                If strLec(iRand) = "" Then
                    GoTo Assign
                End If
            wksCal.Range("D" & j) = strLec(iRand)
            If wksCal.Range("D" & j) = wksCal.Range("D" & j - 1) Then
                GoTo Lector
            End If
        ElseIf wksCal.Range("C" & j) = "EM" Then
    EM:
            iRand = Int((iRows - 2) * Rnd())
                If strEM(iRand) = "" Then
                    GoTo Assign
                End If
            wksCal.Range("D" & j) = strEM(iRand)
            If wksCal.Range("D" & j) = wksCal.Range("D" & j - 1) Then
                GoTo EM
            End If
        ElseIf wksCal.Range("C" & j) = "Altar Server" Then
    Server:
            iRand = Int((iRows - 2) * Rnd())
                If strAS(iRand) = "" Then
                    GoTo Assign
                End If
            wksCal.Range("D" & j) = strAS(iRand)
            If wksCal.Range("D" & j) = wksCal.Range("D" & j - 1) Then
                GoTo Server
            End If
        End If

    Next j
```

Comment: Remove the already chosen volunteers from the pool remaining before each pick. ANd then reset the entire pool for the start of each day

Comment: The only problem is, it assigns volunteers for one month at a time. Volunteers can be assigned to different dates, just not different positions on the same date.

Comment: As @PieterGeerkens said *Remove the already chosen volunteers from the pool remaining before each pick* ... but just reset the pool when you start processing a new date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a suggestion about how to manage the list of volunteers

```
 With wkscal
        Dim a()
        ReDim a(irows) ' volunteers index list
        For s = 1 To 3    ' 3 dates to fill
            With .Cells((s - 1) * 8 + 1, 1)
            ' fill volunteers index list
                For i = 1 To irows
                    a(i) = i
                Next
                '
                For i = 1 To 8    '8 positions to fill per date
                'choose an index in the list of remaining valid index
                    q = Application.RandBetween(1, irows - i + 1)
                    .Range("D" & i) = strlec(a(q))
                    ' remove the last chosen index from the list
                    a(q) = a(irows - i + 1)
                Next i
            End With
        Next s
    End With
```